# java.io.NotSerializableException with serializable data class in Kotlin (kotlinx.serialization)

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class, kotlinx.serialization

I'm facing `java.io.NotSerializableException` when trying to `writeObject` and object of a `data class` into an `ObjectOutputStream`.
Following is the main activity function of my project :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        debug()
    }
    fun debug() {
        val oos = ObjectOutputStream(ByteArrayOutputStream())
        val obj = BaseElement("HELLO WORLD")
        try{
            oos.writeObject(obj)
        }
        catch(e : Exception) {
            Log.d("mydebug", e.stackTraceToString())
        }
    }
}
```

The `BaseElement` class can be found here :

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class BaseElement(var sentence : String)
```

The stacktracke is as following :

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.myproject.model.BaseElement
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
        at com.example.myproject.MainActivity.debug(MainActivity.kt:29)
        at com.example.myproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8130)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8110)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1343)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3781)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3977)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:109)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2374)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)
```

Someone please help me understand the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the serializable interface

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable


data class BaseElement(var sentence : String) : Serializable
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, but this is not completely correct.
We won't need to import kotlinx serialization and the Serializable interface will be used from java.io
Please update you answer to `import java.io.*`

Comment: yeah , both imports will work @VishalMahavar